# Not able to retrive values from common X path

Tags: java, arrays, selenium-webdriver

I needed to display the text from multiple web elements which shares a common Xpath.

**Below is the code that I used:**

```
List<WebElement> cmtnames =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='issue_actions_container']/div/div/div/div[2]/a")); 
System.out.println(cmtnames.size());

List<String> cmtlist = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int u=0;u<cmtnames.size();u++) 
{                               
cmtlist.add(cmtnames.get(u).getText());
System.out.println(cmtnames.get(u).getText());
}
```

**Code explanation:**
Since Xpath has multiple elements, I used List of  to store it and stored those web elements texts in a Array. The size of those web elements shows but during the Run, it showed only first two element values and third one displayed as blank.

Note: the above mentioned scenario is working correctly when I reduce the zoom level of the window from (100 to 90) but reducing this zoom level does not seems to be a strategic solution all the time as the Xpath may contains more than 3 web elements hence its impossible to define accurate zoom size that will satisfy all such scenarios. please suggest me a better solution.

Comment: Can you check if all the 3 elements exists in the browser debugger(F12) for `[@id='issue_actions_container']/div/div/div/div[2]/a`?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='issue_actions_container']/div/div/div/div[2]/a"));
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform(); // to move to the element

List<WebElement> cmtnames =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='issue_actions_container']/div/div/div/div[2]/a"));
for(WebElement e : cmtnames ){
System.out.println(e.getText()); // to print all the elements
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the loop in the question?

Comment: it's still not producing the entire values with the code you provided. @theGuy

Comment: RajeevRanjan, my answer is correct implementation of 'List' as it fetches all the webelements and store in a data structure so there is no need to store them in an array again. 
@Rathish_Logan, if your code is working on zoom out there are chances these elements are not visible on normal screen size. Since Selenium Webdriver tries to simulate real users, it cannot interact with elements which are invisible/hidden. First you can try to move to the element using Actions. I have added code to my answer. Please let me know if this worked.

Comment: @theGuy, You are correct, the values that are not displaying is hidden from the window, now how can I scroll down and get the remaining invisible WebElements values?

Comment: @Rathish_Logan, first 3 lines of my code will move to that element (you can also use it on parent element) and then use 'List' to get all the elements.

Comment: @theGuy, below code is working absolutely fine for me. no need of adding Action function here, it will fetch the value no matter it's hidden or visible

List<WebElement> cmtnames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='issue_actions_container']/div/div/div/div[2]/a"));
   
   Object texts = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
            "return jQuery(arguments[0]).text();", cmtnames);

Comment: @Rathish_Logan, once you know the root cause of the issue you can try different ways to resolve. Ofcourse you can use javascript for this action but I prefer working with selenium locators as much I can to avoid any performance issues. I am glad javascript solution worked for you, btw did you got chance to try Actions?